# How do I extract the rows from another dataframe based on a datetime constraint?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Basically I am trying to answer the question: "What are the clients most recent 4 orders from X date..." but the problem is I am trying to do that for each row in a table that is ordered by email logs and that have a unique date.

So I would have to look at each date in those email logs (df1), find out if the agent_id in df1 matches the agent_id df2 (order history), and then pull the most recent 4 orders from df2. I.E: Client 123 receives an email on March 3rd (df1)... Then I would need to pull the 4 most recent entries of client 123 in df2 that are equal or less than the date (March 3rd).

I came up with this messy function but it's not really practical when looping over 1000s of rows... Any ideas for scaling this up?

Thanks,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'agent_id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'created_at_email': ['1/5/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/8/2020', '1/8/2020']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'agent_id': [1, 1, 3, 1], 'created_at': ['1/4/2020', '1/5/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/9/2020']})

# note: super not optimized at all...
def function():
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        for index, row2 in df2.iterrows():
            if row['agent_id'] == row2['agent_id']:
                if row2['created_at'] <= row['created_at_email']:
                    print( 1, row2['created_at'], row['created_at_email'], row2['agent_id'], row['agent_id'], row['unique_col'], row2['unique_col'])
                else:
                    print( 0, row2['created_at'], row['created_at_email'], row2['agent_id'], row['agent_id'], row['unique_col'], row2['unique_col'])
            #else:
                #print( 0, row2['created_at'], row['created_at_email'], row2['agent_id'], row['agent_id'])
                    
                    
            
function()
```

```
output:
1 1/4/2020 1/5/2020 1 1 a a
1 1/5/2020 1/5/2020 1 1 a b
0 1/9/2020 1/5/2020 1 1 a d
1 1/6/2020 1/8/2020 3 3 c c
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we need to do a correspondence between `df1` and `df2` to retrieve the `created_at_email`

To do this you can set both dataframes indexes to be the `agent_id` column, after this we can join both dataframes

```
df1.index = df1.agent_id
df2.index = df2.agent_id
result = df2.join(df1,lsuffix='_df2')
```

The `join` method match based on the equality of the index.

We will reset the index of `result` to prevent errors during the `groupby` and also remove the unnecessary columns

```
result.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
result.drop(['agent_id_df2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

To maintain the most recent orders of each `agent_id` we will sort the dataframe on `created_at` and `agent_id`

```
result.sort_values(['agent_id','created_at'],inplace=True)
```

After that you can do a `groupby` with the `head` method to retrieve the 4 recent orders of each agent

```
result = result.groupby('agent_id').head(4)
```

#### Final Result

|  | unique_col_df2 | created_at | unique_col | agent_id | created_at_email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1/4/2020 | a | 1 | 1/5/2020 |
| 1 | b | 1/5/2020 | a | 1 | 1/5/2020 |
| 2 | d | 1/9/2020 | a | 1 | 1/5/2020 |
| 3 | c | 1/6/2020 | c | 3 | 1/8/2020 |

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I think I should've specified... "So I would have to look at each date in those email logs (df1), find out if the agent_id in df1 matches the agent_id df2 (order history), and then pull the most recent 4 orders from df2 EDIT: from the date in df1. I.E: So if client 123 in df1 got an email on March 3rd. I would need to look in the order logs (df2) and grab the 4 most recent entries (rows) from that date in df1 (March 3rd). Client 123 can appear in df1 multiple times, the unique separator is the date. Thanks!